# OneDrive / SkyDrive crashing on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, onedrive

I have upgraded from Window 8 to 8.1 Pro with Media Center (fully updated) and OneDrive has started crashing with the following dump.

```
Problem signature:  
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: skydrive.exe
  Application Version:  6.3.9600.17484
  Application Timestamp:    545d76bd
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_4cdf
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   00000000
  Exception Offset: PCH_32_FROM_KERNEL32+0x00000000000EAABE
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.103
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 4cdf
  Additional Information 2: 4cdf021cc0b2992ec7c50ce49266caf5
  Additional Information 3: 29ef
  Additional Information 4: 29efc2092bac35b11852d06f8f045b15

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

After numerous Google searches, I came across [this](https://ssgoku129.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/onedrive-constantly-crashing-and-restarting-on-windows-8-1-fix/) entry related to symbolic folder mapping. The mapping was pointing to SkyDrive and I changed that to OneDrive and rebooted but the problem still persists.

I also don't see a way of uninstalling/reinstalling OneDrive as it seems baked into Windows 8.1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The face the application name is still `skydrive.exe` indicates something strange is going on because it shouldn't be that.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes I thought so as well but since OneDrive is supposed to be baked into Windows 8.1, I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the [OneDrive troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/onedrive-troubleshooter), that had to be run a few times in vain before it finally fixed the problem. OneDrive still occasionally crashes but it at least functional most of the time.